# use of deleted function in using ifstream

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a file and save its handler in an struct and then insert the struct into a map. Here is a simple code snippet I wrote. I get the `use of deleted function` compile error. Is this because the fileHandle of type ifstream cannot be copied so the entire struct cannot be copied? How can I solve the issue?

```
typedef struct speedEntry
{
    std::ifstream fileHandle;
} speedEntry_t;

std::map<uint32_t, speedEntry_t> allSpeed;

speedEntry_t entry = {};

entry.fileHandle.open("path_to_file", std::ifstream::in);
if(!entry.fileHandle.is_open())
    throw an error here;

allSpeed.insert(std::make_pair(1, entry));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifstream`s are not copyable, your code is trying to copy insert them into the `allSpeed` map, change the line of code that does the insertion to this

```
allSpeed.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::move(entry)));
```

i.e. move the `entry` object into the map

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly the reason, as seen [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) the copy constructor for your `ifstream` is:

> basic_ifstream( const basic_ifstream& rhs) = delete;

deleted.

However, the move constructor isn't, so you can explicitly specify you want to move the lvalue, you cannot reuse `entry` afterwards though:

```
allSpeed.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::move(entry)));
```

Comment: FGITW we meet again.

Comment: @Curious Just in general, actually.